# Android AsyncTask crash

Tags: android, multithreading, crash, android-asynctask

I'm extending AsyncTask and in my doInBackground() I get a button view using findViewById and when I call button.performClick() my app crashes.

Any idea why?

this is the logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(604): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
E/AndroidRuntime(604): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
E/AndroidRuntime(604): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4039)
E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.playSoundEffect(ViewRootImpl.java:3610)
E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.view.View.playSoundEffect(View.java:13103)
E/AndroidRuntime(604):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3510)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm extending AsyncTask and in my doInBackground() I get a button view using findViewById and when I call button.performClick() my app crashes.

In AsyncTasks you can only work with UI elements, like Buttons, in `onProgressUpdate()`, `onPostExecute()` or other methods that have access to the UI thread. Simply move the code that calls on `button` into an acceptable method.

Comment: @Sam : and onPreExecute() too . the only method that you can't modify a view is in the method doInBackground()

Comment: @Houcine Yes, there are more methods that I didn't list but they documented in [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#pubmethods) for anyone that is interested.

Comment: @Sam : And...you can add your own methods to a class which extends `AsyncTask` and they can also access the UI. ;)